# Share ID from Facebook real time subscriptions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, share

I am getting real-time updates on my Facebook fan page. In shares data (`item=share`) it returns the `share_id`. I am trying to call this id but I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to call this id to get the share info?